Flutter widget test won't work when using StreamBuilder, snapshot connection state is always waiting
When I try to check a widget test (I haven't implemented it yet) the test throws an error because it couldn't find the widget I'm searching. I debugged the code and it stops at the part where it selects the screen depending on the snapshot data, because the connection state is in Waiting.
This is my test code, where I mock the Firebase services and then I try to test the screen:
void main(){
  setupFirebaseAuthMocks();
  User? user;

  setUp(() async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    final googleSignIn = MockGoogleSignIn();
    final googleSignInAcc = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    final googleAuth = await googleSignInAcc?.authentication;
    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth?.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth?.idToken
    );
    final mockedUser = MockUser(
        isAnonymous: false,
        uid: 'testingUID',
        email: 'test@somedomain.com',
        displayName: 'Test'
    );
    final auth = MockFirebaseAuth(mockUser: mockedUser);
    final result = await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    user = result.user;

    dotenv.testLoad(fileInput: File('assets/.env').readAsStringSync());
  });

  testWidgets('test', (tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(const LoginScreen());
    await tester.pump(Duration.zero);
    var textFields = find.byType(TextFormField);
    expect(textFields, findsNWidgets(2));
  });

}

And this is the screen I'm trying to test, I want to go to the last case, where the user is not logged in. I'm using Firebase Auth for the login and BLoC to manage the user's state:
class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<LoginScreen> createState() => LoginScreenState();
}

class LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  late bool _passwordVisible;
  late TextEditingController passwordController;
  late TextEditingController emailController;
  final AuthService service = AuthService();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _passwordVisible = false;
    passwordController = TextEditingController();
    emailController = TextEditingController();
  }

  bool isEmailValid(String email) {
    RegExp reg = RegExp(r'^[\w-.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$');
    return reg.hasMatch(email);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ColorScheme colors = Theme.of(context).colorScheme;
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          UserModel temp =
              UserModel(id: snapshot.data!.uid, email: snapshot.data!.email!);
          context.read<AuthenticationBloc>().add(UpdateUserEvent(temp));
          return const MenuScreen();
        }
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return AlertDialog(
                    title: const Text(Texts.error),
                    content: Text(snapshot.error.toString()),
                    actions: <Widget>[
                      ElevatedButton(
                        child: const Text(Texts.close),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        },
                      ),
                    ]);
              });
        }
        return SafeArea(
            child: Scaffold(
                body: CustomScrollView(slivers: [
          SliverFillRemaining(
              hasScrollBody: false,
              child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                      child: LogoAvatar(radius: 150),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        controller: emailController,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.person,
                                size: 50, color: colors.primary),
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: colors.surface,
                            labelText: Texts.email),
                        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                        validator: (email) => email == null || email.isEmpty
                            ? Texts.emailNotEmpty
                            : !isEmailValid(email)
                                ? Texts.emailFormat
                                : null,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        controller: passwordController,
                        obscureText: !_passwordVisible,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.password,
                                size: 50, color: colors.primary),
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: colors.surface,
                            labelText: Texts.password,
                            suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(
                                    _passwordVisible
                                        ? Icons.visibility_off
                                        : Icons.visibility,
                                    color: colors.primary),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _passwordVisible = !_passwordVisible;
                                  });
                                })),
                        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                        validator: (passwd) => passwd != null && passwd.isEmpty
                            ? Texts.passwordNotEmpty
                            : null,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: [
                          MaterialButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              showDialog(
                                  context: context,
                                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                    TextEditingController cont =
                                        TextEditingController();
                                    return AlertDialog(
                                      title: const Text(Texts.resetPasswd),
                                      content: Column(
                                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                        children: [
                                          TextFormField(
                                              controller: cont,
                                              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                                  labelText: Texts.email),
                                              autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode
                                                  .onUserInteraction,
                                              validator: (email) =>
                                                  email == null ||
                                                          email.trim().isEmpty
                                                      ? Texts.emailNotEmpty
                                                      : !isEmailValid(email)
                                                          ? Texts.emailFormat
                                                          : null),
                                          Row(
                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                            children: [
                                              MaterialButton(
                                                onPressed: () =>
                                                    Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                                                child: const Text(Texts.cancel),
                                              ),
                                              MaterialButton(
                                                onPressed: () {
                                                  String email =
                                                      cont.text.trim();
                                                  if (email.isNotEmpty &&
                                                      isEmailValid(email)) {
                                                    service.resetPassword(
                                                        email: email);
                                                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                                    showDialog(
                                                        context: context,
                                                        builder: (BuildContext
                                                            context) {
                                                          return AlertDialog(
                                                              title: const Text(
                                                                  Texts
                                                                      .resetPasswd),
                                                              content: Text(
                                                                  "${Texts.resetPasswdEmailSent} $email"),
                                                              actions: <Widget>[
                                                                MaterialButton(
                                                                    child: const Text(
                                                                        Texts
                                                                            .close),
                                                                    onPressed:
                                                                        () {
                                                                      Navigator.of(
                                                                              context)
                                                                          .pop();
                                                                    }),
                                                              ]);
                                                        });
                                                  }
                                                },
                                                child: const Text("Continue"),
                                              )
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  });
                            },
                            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                            splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                            highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                            child: Text(Texts.forgotPassword,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: colors.primary,
                                    decoration: TextDecoration.underline)),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
                      child: MaterialButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            service
                                .signInEmailPassword(
                                    email: emailController.text,
                                    password: passwordController.text)
                                .then((value) {
                              if (value != null) {
                                context
                                    .read<AuthenticationBloc>()
                                    .add(UpdateUserEvent(value));
                              } else {
                                String message;
                                if (emailController.text.isEmpty) {
                                  message = Texts.emailNotEmpty;
                                } else if (passwordController.text.isEmpty) {
                                  message = Texts.passwordNotEmpty;
                                } else {
                                  message = Texts.accountNotExist;
                                }
                                showDialog(
                                    context: context,
                                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                      return AlertDialog(
                                          title: const Text(Texts.error),
                                          content: Text(message),
                                          actions: <Widget>[
                                            MaterialButton(
                                                child: const Text(Texts.close),
                                                onPressed: () =>
                                                    Navigator.of(context)
                                                        .pop()),
                                          ]);
                                    });
                              }
                            });
                          },
                          shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
                          color: colors.primary,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                            child: Text(
                              Texts.login,
                              style: TextStyle(color: colors.surface),
                            ),
                          )),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
                      child: SizedBox(
                        width: 220,
                        child: MaterialButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              service.signInGoogle().then((user) {
                                if (user != null) {
                                  APIManager.saveData(
                                      json: user.toJson(),
                                      endpointPlural: Texts.usersEndpoint);
                                  context
                                      .read<AuthenticationBloc>()
                                      .add(UpdateUserEvent(user));
                                }
                              });
                            },
                            elevation: 3.0,
                            color: colors.surface,
                            shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100))),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  SvgPicture.asset(Resources.googleLogoAsset,
                                      colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                                          colors.primary, BlendMode.srcIn),
                                      width: 30),
                                  Text(
                                    Texts.googleSignIn,
                                    style: TextStyle(color: colors.primary),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            )),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
                      child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Text(Texts.dontHaveAccount,
                                style: TextStyle(color: colors.primary)),
                            MaterialButton(
                                onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) =>
                                            const RegisterScreen())),
                                splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                                highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                                child: Text(Texts.register,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: colors.primary,
                                        decoration: TextDecoration.underline)))
                          ]),
                    )
                  ]))
        ])));
      },
    );
  }
}


Usually this kind of problem can be solved by either using pumpAndSettle or runAsync

@DhafinRayhan Yes! That worked, thank you a lot! I used the pumpAndSettle method
